How does argocd render a resource graph?
i have an argocd instance that shows all the custom resources deployed by a project as a flat list.
something like this:
project -> obj1
        -> obj2
        -> obj3
        -> obj4

ideally the graph should look like:
project -> obj1 -> obj2
        -> obj3
        -> obj4 -> obj5 -> obj6

obj2,obj4,obj5 and6 have owner references set.
Does anyone know which annotations/labels/etc. is argo looking for to render a dependency graph?
